# Different join/update based on case query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, case

I am trying to use the following code to run a different `join` query, based on a `CASE` statement.

So if the `customer CLI`  is equal to `84422881` I want it to join based on the `[Extenstion]` field and if the condition is not met i.e. the `ELSE` then to join on `[Customer CLI]`

```
use VoiceflexBilling

CASE WHEN [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerCLI] = '84422881' THEN

UPDATE [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
SET [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerLookup] = CLIMapping.[customer id] 
FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] 
INNER JOIN [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
on [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[Extension] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping].[CLI]

ELSE

UPDATE [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
SET [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerLookup] = CLIMapping.[customer id] 
FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] 
INNER JOIN [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
on [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerCLI] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping].[CLI]

END
```

At the moment I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'CASE'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11 Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'ELSE'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19 Incorrect syntax
>   near 'END'.

Can anyone help with the correct syntax?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `case` statement in the `join condition`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
SET [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerLookup] = CLIMapping.[customer id] 
FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] 
INNER JOIN [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
ON [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping].[CLI] = 
 CASE WHEN [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerCLI] = '84422881' 
                 THEN [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[Extension]
      ELSE [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerCLI] 
 END
```

Answer (score 3):

Some comments on your query.  First, `case` is an *expression*, not control flow.  So, it belongs inside a query.  Second, you can just use "regular" logic for this query.  Third, table aliases would make the query much easier to write and to read:

```
UPDATE c 
SET c.[CustomerLookup] = CLIMapping.[customer id] 
FROM [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] cm
     [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] c INNER JOIN
     on (c.[CustomerCLI] = '84422881' AND c.[Extension] = cm.[CLI]) or
        (c.[CustomerCLI] <> '84422881' AND c.[CustomerCLI] = cm.[CLI])
```

Answer (score 0):

Case must be appear inside a query.for your scenario I suggest you to write your code as follow:(you me need to implement looping for iterate over all records and in that case you will need to modify this code little a bit)

```
DECLARE @p varchar(100)
SET @p=(SELECT TOP 1 [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerCLI] FROM [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls])
IF @p = '84422881'
   UPDATE [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
   SET [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerLookup] = CLIMapping.[customer id] 
   FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] 
   INNER JOIN [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
   on [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[Extension] =[BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping].[CLI]

ELSE
   UPDATE [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
   SET [dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerLookup] = CLIMapping.[customer id] 
   FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] 
   INNER JOIN [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls] 
   on [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[MARU15_OWH07579_Calls].[CustomerCLI] = [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping].[CLI]
```